# How to retrieve column name for a unique id and unique value

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve column names from a table which having `Boolean` value for a unique id like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'my table name' AND table_schema = 'database name' AND user_id = '1' AND category = '1'
```

Comment: This can never work-as is. You cannot join a field in one table against the VALUE of some other field in another table. And if you already know the names of your boolean fields, why are you querying information_schema to begin with?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc. it's going to work dynamically this Boolean value changing for every user.

Comment: so? it's a field in your table. `select * from yourtable where booleanfield=true` will get you ALL records where that field is true.

Comment: I want the category name's which is the field names in my table. i want to know the members came under a category. little change in my question sorry for that SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'my table name' AND table_schema = 'database name' AND user_id = '1' AND CLUMN_NAME = '1'

Comment: and like I said, your query is impossible. what you want cannot be done in a single query. you'd have to retrieve the table's field names from information scheme, build a NEW query using those field names, blah blah blah. if your tables have random/arbitrary field names, then your design is massively flawed and will cause no end of agony and hairpulling, exactly as it is right now.

Comment: Then how to achieve with multiple query, can u give me an example for that Marc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table looks like:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+
| id  | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | ... | col_N |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+
| 1   | true  | NULL  | false | ... | true  |
| 2   | NULL  | NULL  | true  | ... | true  |
| 3   | false | false | true  | ... | true  |
| ... | ...   | ...   | ...   | ... | ...   |
| M   | true  | true  | NULL  | ... | false |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+
```

then:

```
select (
        concat(
            if(col_1, 'col_1, ', ''),
            if(col_2, 'col_2, ', ''),
            if(col_3, 'col_3, ', ''),
            ...
            if(col_N, 'col_N, ', '')
        )
    ) as `list_of_cols` 
from 
    `table_name` 
where `id` = id_value;
```

the result will look like:

```
+----------------------+
|     list_of_cols     |
+----------------------+
| col_1, col_5, col_6, |
+----------------------+
```